# PHP date returning wrong time

Tags: php, date

The following script is returning the wrong time after I call `date_default_timezone_set("UTC")`

```
<?PHP   
    $timestamp = time();
    echo "<p>Timestamp: $timestamp</p>";

    // This returns the correct time
    echo "<p>". date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp) ."</p>";


    echo "<p>Now I call 'date_default_timezone_set(\"UTC\")' and echo out the same timestamp.</p>";
    echo "Set timezone = " . date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

    // This returns a time 5 hours in the past
    echo "<p>". date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp) ."</p>";

?>
```

The timezone on the server is **BST**. So what should happen is that the second call to 'date' should return a time 1 hour behind the first call. It's actually returning a time 5 hours behind the first one.

I should note that the server was originally set up with the EDT timezone (UTC -4). That was changed to BST (UTC +1) and the server was restarted.

I can't figure out if this is a PHP problem or a problem with the server.

Comment: What is date_default_timezone_get() showing *before* you change the timezone?

Comment: Time zone: Europe/London

Comment: And what is your server's `date` terminal command returns?

Comment: -bash-3.2$ date  -> 

Fri Apr 13 12:08:21 BST 2012

Comment: That time is completely wrong either way. Run `ntpdate` to correct your computer's clock (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is almost certainly not an error in php, but in your local timezone configuration.

Most likely, you didn't actually change the system-wide time zone, but only that of an interactive display. Check that `/etc/localtime` matches what you'd expect. On debian systems, you can run tzselect (with superuser privileges) to set the system-wide timezone.

After setting the timezone, you may have to reset your clock. On many systems, that should happen automatically over time, but you can do it manually by running `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org`.

Comment: Where to run `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org`. ? In cpanel ?

Comment: @TarangP On a command line shell on the system you have, typically via ssh. If all you have is cpanel, see the [cpanel documentation on how to access the command line](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Access+the+Command+Line). cpanel also has [its own NTP/time interface, which can be used instead](https://www.buycpanel.com/what-is-the-server-time-interface-responsible-for-in-cpanel/).

Comment: ```tzselect``` I used this on ubuntu, configured the timezone well and restarted apache2 but I still get the wrong date!

Answer (score 5):

just set your region with following code

```
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");//set you countary name from below timezone list
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());//now it will show "Asia/Bangkok" or your date time
```

List of Supported Timezones
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: That one helped me showing current time once on shared hosting, onle the time() is not really needed... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should check the php manual for the correct timezone of your country. Then set it in the date_default_timezone_set () function. For clarification, I explained it here http://t2techblog.com/php-a-simple-function-for-getting-the-current-nigeria-local-time/

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example.

Comment: Example: a simple function that returns the correct time in my country(Nigeria) with a welcome message. 

<?php 
function get_ng_time() {
 
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
     
    $time = date('h:i A');
    $message = 'Hello, welcome to my blog. It is '.$time.' here in Nigeria.';
    return $message;
}
?>

Comment: I'm really sorry that the function and my texts are kind of jam-packed together. I'm new here.. Still figuring out how things work