# Not showing me the todays date

Tags: php, date, mktime

```
<?php   
        for ( $i=1; $i<13; $i++ ) {
        $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
        $sel = ( $i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options1[] = "<option  value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$month}</option>";
}
        $options_list1 = join("", $options1);
        echo "<select name=\"month\" >{$options_list1}</select>";

        for ( $j=1; $j<32; $j++ ) {
        $theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$j,2000));
        $sel = ( $j == date('d') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options2[] = "<option  value=\"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}</option>";
}
        $options_list2 = join("\r\n", $options2);
        echo "<select name=\"day\" >{$options_list2}</select>";

      for ( $k=1960; $k<2016; $k++ ) {
      $theyear = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$k));
       $sel1 = ( $k == date("Y") ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options3[] = "<option  value=\"{$theyear}\" {$sel1}>{$theyear}</option>";
}
        $options_list3 = join("\r\n", $options3);
        echo "<select name=\"year\" >{$options_list3}</select>";
        ?>
```

This is a dropdown for date,month and year . Its showing today month and year but in the date its showing me yesterday date for eg today date is 9/22/2013 and its showing me 9/21/2013 . what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date returning wrong time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139843/php-date-returning-wrong-time)

Comment: You have timezone issues. Server/script timezone is different than your local timezone. See the output of the `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s);` and compare it with your local time. Set timezone with [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: @Glavić , I am working on my localhost server , its showing me my system date

Comment: If `echo date('d);` returns `22` and you are still in `21` then you have timezone issue. If it returns `21` then you have no problem, because the script should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your timezone using `date_default_timezone_set` in `php.ini`

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)