# Why is a year being added to my date when I change the format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a bootstrap date picker in a form and then pass that form value to a PHP page.

When I echo the variable that I send to the PHP page everything displays as it did when I selected the date from the drop-down calendar.

However, the date in my calendar is a different format to the date structure in my MYSQL database and  I use the following piece of code to reformat it.

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$sales_date);
 $nsales_date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Below is an example the variable sales_date displays as 18/08/2016

but once I have run the code above the variable nsales_date shows the reformated date as  2017-06-08

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date returning wrong time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139843/php-date-returning-wrong-time)

Comment: Instead of formatting it, why not saves date as timestamps? `DateTime::getTimestamp()`

Comment: How many months are there in a year: I've been alive 55 years, and none of those have had 18 months or more.... `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$sales_date);`

Comment: Because it read the month as 18 (and months only go up to 12, so that adds extra months, puts you in next year). You have 'm/d/Y' but you mean 'd/m/Y'

Comment: How did i not see that? its been driving me mad

Comment: @StanWilliams - One of the benefits of peer review and/or pair programming